# Change the paypal item name in the PayPal Express Checkout plugin

Tags: wordpress, express, woocommerce, paypal

I have a WordPress site using the PayPal Checkout plugin for woocommerce.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/

I need to change the PayPal item name and I'm using this code in the functions.php, it worked with the normal PayPal plugin but does not work with PayPal Express checkout.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_get_order_item_name', 'change_paypal_item_name', 10, 3 );
function change_paypal_item_name( $item_name, $order, $item ) {
    return 'test';
}
```

Anyone know the function to change the item name with the PayPal Express checkout plugin?

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look at [the code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/blob/6683c964bfa9444e83ab2a26288cdab7e19d952b/includes/class-wc-gateway-ppec-client.php#L659), it seems `woocommerce_paypal_express_checkout_get_details` is a filter you can try implementing to modify the whole `$details` array

Comment: Thanks, i've tried this code, but seems it did not work.
<code>add_filter( 'woocommerce_paypal_express_checkout_get_details', 'change_paypal_item_name', 10, 3 );
function change_paypal_item_name( $details ) {
 if (count($details['items'])) {
  $items = array();
  foreach ($details['items'] as $item) {
   $item['name'] = 'test';
   $items[] = $item;
  }
  $details['items'] = $items;
 }
 return $details;
}</code>